# How do I build an expression to apply a Where clause generically to an IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, expression-trees

I have a class called `TestObject` with a `Name` parameter.

I create a list and add 2 of these. I want to create a generic `Where()` clause method for any `IQueryable<T>`.

I've been playing around with Expressions but I don't really know what I'm doing.

I created this method with some hardcoded values for testing, I want it to do `collection.Where(c => c.Name == "Boris")`:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Apply<T>(IQueryable<T> collection)
{
    var parameterName = "Name";
    var searchValue = "Boris";

    var selectorParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), parameterName);
    var searchTermExpression = Expression.Constant(searchValue);    
    var checkEqualsExpression = Expression.Call(selectorParameter, typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals"), searchTermExpression);

var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { collection.ElementType },
    collection.Expression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(checkEqualsExpression , ?????));

    return collection.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(methodCallExpression);
}
```

I'm not sure what goes in `?????` or even if this is correct. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Are you sure the `Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), parameterName)` parameterName is of type `T`. It's a property of `T`  (it's a string i guess). You might need the `Expression.Property()` for that

Comment: I don't know, I copied and pasted it from another site that did something similar to what I wanted and I am trying to make it work but I don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it, with comments, it should clarify what you are doing wrong.

```
public static IQueryable<T> Apply<T>(IQueryable<T> collection) {
    var propertyName = "Name";
    var searchValue = "Boris";
    // we have parameter "c"
    var selectorParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
    // constant "Boris"
    var searchTermExpression = Expression.Constant(searchValue);
    // "c.Name"
    var selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(selectorParameter, propertyName);
    // "c.Name == "Boris"
    var equal = Expression.Equal(selector, searchTermExpression);
    // c => c.Name == "Boris"
    var where = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equal, selectorParameter);
    return collection.Where(where);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a lot simpler than what I was trying to do! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @NibblyPig don't forget to mark as answer if you have to additional questions, or people will come again and again to this question and waste their time thinking it is still unanswered.

Comment: @Evk I know, I wanted to test it first :) It worked great and I was able to expand it to do loads of other cool stuff. Many thanks I really appreciate it.